# Replace symbols space and plus to URL code

Tags: swift, rest, request

I need to send get request on server with query parameters, but query contains symbols <kbd>+</kbd> and spaces. How I can encode it to url code? Like symbol plus to %2B and spaces to %20.

Basic URLQueryItem don't have URL code argument and didn't work correctly (just send <kbd>+</kbd> like <kbd>+</kbd> without encode).

Answer (score 0):

you need to put URLEncoding.default in ParameterEncoding and adding key values in Parameter like

```
case .callingAPIs(let getValue):
   return ["value" : getValue]


let encoding: ParameterEncoding = {
     return URLEncoding.default
}
```

then you will get your desire result